# How should we handle SQL exceptions in the DAO layer?

Tags: sql, hibernate, exception

How should we handle SQLExceptions in the DAO layer using Hibernate?

Answer (score 0):

Create the `class EmployeeDaoImpl.java`

```
package com.mypro.module.emp.dao;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import org.apache.commons.dbutils.DbUtils;

import com.mypro.module.emp.exception.EmployeeException;
import com.mypro.module.emp.model.Employee;

public class EmployeeDaoImpl extends JdbcDaoSupportImpl implements EmployeeDao {

    @Override
    public int save(Employee employee) throws EmployeeException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String sql = "INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES(?,?,?)";
        Connection conToUse = null;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        int status = 0;
        try {
            conToUse = getConnection();
            ps = conToUse.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setInt(1, employee.getEmpNo());
            ps.setString(2, employee.getEmpName());
            ps.setLong(3, employee.getEmpSal());
            status = ps.executeUpdate();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            throw new EmployeeException(
                    "%%% Exception occured in EmployeeDao save() %%% " + e);
        } finally {
            DbUtils.closeQuietly(ps);
        }
        return status;
    }

}
```